# Django import-export library ForeignKey error (IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in django)

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

First of all please sorry for my English. ))

So I have a problem with Django import-export library when I try to import data from `csv/xls/xlsx` files to the Django application DB.

How it looks like.

Here is my **models.py:**

```
class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = '')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.department_name}'

class ITHardware(models.Model):
    it_hardware_model = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    it_hardware_serial_number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, 
        blank = True, default = '')
    it_hardware_department = models.ForeignKey(Department, 
        related_name = 'department', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, default = '', 
        null = True, blank = True, db_constraint=False)
```

**admin.py:**

```
@admin.register(Department)
class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('department_name', )
    actions = [duplicate_object]

@admin.register(ITHardwareManufacturer)
class ITHardwareManufacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('manufacturer', )
    actions = [duplicate_object]

class ITHardwareImportExportAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ITHardwareResource
    list_display = ['id', 'it_hardware_manufacturer', 
        'it_hardware_model', 'it_hardware_serial_number', 
        'it_hardware_department']
    actions = [duplicate_object]
```

**resource.py:**

```
class ITHardwareResource(resources.ModelResource):
    it_hardware_department = fields.Field(
        column_name = 'it_hardware_department',
        attribute = 'ITHardware.it_hardware_department',
        widget = widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(Department, field = 'department_name'))
    
    class Meta():
        model = ITHardware
        fields = (
            'id',
            'it_hardware_model', 
            'it_hardware_serial_number', 
            'it_hardware_department', 
            )
        export_order = (
            'id',
            'it_hardware_model', 
            'it_hardware_serial_number', 
            'it_hardware_department', 
            )
```

**import file:**

[image: import file]

If I try to import data from file, I get such error:

```
String number: 1 - ITHardwareManufacturer matching query does not exist.
None, Canon, BX500CI, 5B1837T00976, Office_1, IT_1
```

And so on.

OK. When I fill Department table manually via `adminpanel` (pointed there IT_1, 2, 3 and 4 departments) I get this preview:

[image: preview]

and then I get this error:

[image: error]

Please explain me what am I doing wrong and how to fix it.

**Update**

If I understood the concept correctly, then "column_name" is the name of the column from which/to which data is imported/exported, and "attribute" is the name of the database field for the same operations.

The export works fine for me.
However, for import, as I understand it, I incorrectly describe the mechanism for ForeignKey. That is, I'm trying to tell Django that when importing data from the "it_hardware_department" column of the file, this data should be written to the "it_hardware_department" field of the Department model using ForeignKeyWidget.

Perhaps some intermediate action is required to determine the mechanism for writing data to the Department model, where to specify something like "Department__it_hardware_department"?

**Update: traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 232, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\http.py", line 40, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py", line 113, in process_import
    result = self.process_dataset(dataset, confirm_form, request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\admin.py", line 125, in process_dataset
    return resource.import_data(dataset,
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 771, in import_data
    return self.import_data_inner(
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\import_export\utils.py", line 25, in __exit__
    self.context_manager.__exit__(*args)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 246, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 266, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\users\iv\mip\mip_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 242, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/mip_apps/ithardware/process_import/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: what happens if you change this `attribute = 'ITHardware.it_hardware_department',` to this: `attribute = 'it_hardware_department'`?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. In fact, I also tried that, however, the result is exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample, the import process will look for a field called `it_hardware_department` in the import file (and we can see that it is there).  During import, it will attempt to find the FK relation in `Department` by doing a simple `get(name=<value in column>`.  It will store this value in `ITHardware.it_hardware_department` - however this won't work because this isn't a valid model field.  You should rename this to `it_hardware_department` (which you said you did).  The fact that shows up in the preview screen tells me that this worked ok.

The 'FK contraint' failed error says that you have tried to write to the table with an invalid FK relationship.  I suggest run the debugger or add a print to inspect the object before it is saved.  It is likely that one of your required Foreign Keys will be empty here.  I don't think it is `it_hardware_department` because this has a value in the preview.  Are there other FKs in your model which are not listed?

Comment: Thanks Matthew!

To clarify: what is displayed in the preview (on the image) - appears only if the data from the "it_hardware_department" column is already contained in the "Department" model.

You're right, there are several other FKs in the model that are not related to the Department model, and with different related_names. Could this be causing my problem?

Comment: yes, add a print() if you can (or debug) to inspect the object, or perhaps increase logging if you can.  This should tell you which FK field is missing

Comment: Hello! :)

I checked the import with another model, with only one FK, the results are as follows: if the model with which the FK is associated already has the value that I am trying to import in the corresponding field, then the import occurs correctly. If there is no such entry, then I get the error "<Model> matching query does not exist."

Can you please tell me how exactly I can trace where the error occurs in this case?

Comment: This simply means that the code is trying to read an FK relationship using the field you have defined ('pk' by default), but that the entry is not present in the table.